# Word to describe "legal ability to advertise"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that describes a "legal ability to advertise" ("... to publish" and "... to communicate" are viable options too). I would like to use it in the following sentence:

> You have 3 days until *advertiseability* of x.

I've considered `communicability` but I think it's related mostly to diseases.

The context is: I'm trying to find a name for a function in a programming language, so it should be short and concise. Something like: `daysUntilAdvertiseabilityOf(x);` Basically, you can publish an ad in three days, but not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the option to reword your example sentence,

> There are 3 days before X is advertisable

or

> There are 3 days before X is publishable

seem like reasonable possibilities.

Comment: Does "get days before publishable x" sound too weird? I'm afraid I have no choice but to put `x` at the end.

Comment: @Oleg - "Get days before publishability of X" more or less works.